# Get DefaultListModel to use LinkedList

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to make a DefaultListModel use the contents of a LinkedList to display?

This is then to be used with a JList.

Comment: Is it possible to put my LinkedList straight into a JList?

Comment: The closest thing you can do is construct a JList and pass in a Vector.  However, I'd recommend subclassing AbstractListModel instead (see my answer) as it means you don't have to resort to JDK 1.1 collections.  If you *do* decide to go this route remember to notify your JList (via the model) if you alter the Vector contents.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible: You simply need to subclass [`AbstractListModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) and override [`getElementAt`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html#getElementAt(int)) and [`getSize`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html#getSize()) to call through to your underlying `LinkedList`.

```
public class MyListModel extends AbstractListModel {
  private final List<?> l;

  public MyListModel(List<?> l) {
    this.l = l;
  }

  public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return l.get(index);
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return l.size();
  }
}
```

**Warning**: When implementing `ListModel` or `TableModel` and backing the model with a `List` I would advise using `ArrayList` over `LinkedList` to ensure O(1) access time when accessing a given element.

Answer (score 2):

`DefaultListModel` uses a `Vector` as the backing list. This is a private member, so you don't really have an option extend and override how it works. If you have to use a `LinkedList`, you'll probably have to write your own list model implementation (say, extend `AbstractListModel` as the default list model does), or loop through your list and add each object to the list model.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you subclass it and override all of the implemented methods, no. but you can add all of the elements from a LinkedList to the DefaultListModel (populating the underlying Vector)

```
for (Object element : linkedList)
    model.addElement(element);
```

or just write your own implementation of AbstractListModel using a LinkedList/List/Collection as the source.